# Java linklist sorting by ID

Tags: java

I have made a program for storing student and courses for the student 
but I want to sort all the student by the ID form smallest to biggest
now I have it for big to small but I don't know how to change it 
I try to change ">" to "<" but its not working.

This is my method for insert

```
    private Student addStudentRecord(Student head, Student tempADDACCOUNT) {
    // IF there is no list, newNode will be the first node, so just return it
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Student(tempADDACCOUNT, head);
        return head;
    }

    // ELSE, we have a list. Insert the new node at the correct location
    else {
        // We need to traverse to the correct insertion location...so we need a help ptr
        Student helpPtr = head;
        // Traverse to correct insertion point
        while (helpPtr.getNext() != null) {
            if (helpPtr.getNext().getID() > tempADDACCOUNT.getID())
                break; // we found our spot and should break out of the while loop
            helpPtr = helpPtr.getNext();
        }
        // Now make the new node. Set its next to point to the successor node.
        // And then make the predecessor node point to the new node
        Student newNode = new Student(tempADDACCOUNT, helpPtr.getNext());
        helpPtr.setNext(newNode);
    }
    // Return head
    return head;
}
```

If you can help me to sorted it on the other way from small to big
this method is the insert method for the linklist.

Comment: Sorting linked list is a bad idea. Each swap takes K-1 times. Consider using an ArrayList or a TreeSet.

Comment: the problem is i have to do it like this, cuz its an project and i have to make it inside the link list so do you know how can i do it ?

Comment: In your case with linked list, you need to maintain another pointer to previous node, if  `helpPtr.getNext().getID() < tempADDACCOUNT.getID()`, you need to append the new node to the previous node.

Comment: so what will be the full code ?

Comment: Implement comparable and then use Collection.sort ?

Comment: Note that OP is not sorting the list after filling it with data, but sorting in each added item, so using `ArrayList` or `Collections.sort()` is irrelevant - the list is (presumably) to be in sort order after every addition.

Answer (score 0):

Continued.. (after the comments to the question)

Something like

```
 Student helpPtr = head;
 Student prev = helpPtr;
 while (helpPtr.getNext() != null) {
    if (helpPtr.getNext().getID() < tempADDACCOUNT.getID())
          break; 
    prev = helpPtr;
    helpPtr = helpPtr.getNext();
 }
 Student newNode = new Student(tempADDACCOUNT, helpPtr);
 prev.setNext(newNode);
```

Note: The code will give you the idea, not tested.

Comment: Let me know if there is a problem with the code provided? Error messages or sample output?

Comment: the probram is print on a file so i don't see ant input cuz its stack i run it for 30 sec but nothing run:
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 30 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

oky i found out how and i fix it :D 
what i change is this

```
if (head == null) {
        head = new Student(tempADDACCOUNT, head);
        return head;
    }
```

i but it like this

```
if (head == null||head.getID()> tempADDACCOUNT.getID()) {
        head = new Student(tempADDACCOUNT, head);
        return head;
    }
```

so all what was the problem on the if i was have to put 
||head.getID()> tempADDACCOUNT.getID()

now every thing working

Answer (score 0):

Sort the linklist using merge sort and than insert the new node according to id

This is my sample code of merge sort `

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
       if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        ListNode fast = head;
        ListNode slow = head;
        ListNode prev = null;

        // get center
        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            prev = slow;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        prev.next = null;
        ListNode l1 = sortList(head);
        ListNode l2 = sortList(slow);
        return mregeList(l1, l2);
    }
    public ListNode mregeList(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        wif (l1 == null) {
            return l2;
        }
        if (l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }
        ListNode result = null;
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
            result = l1;
            result.next = mregeList(l1.next, l2);
        } else {
            result = l2;
            result.next = mregeList(l1, l2.next);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can modify the code according as you need.
Thanks hope this will be helpful.